# Equation $2\cos(x)-3\tan(x)=0$

Tags: trigonometry

I solved this equation $2\cos(x)-3\tan(x)=0$ and I got, $\frac{1}{2}=\sin(x)$ and $-2=\sin(x)$.

For the first solution I got $\arcsin(1/2)=x, 30°=x$, but second is invalid because the domain of arcsin can be only between $-1$ and $1$.

Right???

Thanks.

EDIT:

My question: is the solution valid for $\arcsin(-2)$, because the domain of $\arcsin()$ is $-1<x<1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're entirely correct. Good work! (We throw out the solution  $\sin x = -2$ for precisely the reason you give. I.e., There is no $x$ such that $\sin x = -2$.)

Comment: this answer could be safely fit into a comment, right??

Comment: @lab Sure it could. But it puts closure on the question, so as not to be "unanswered." What does answering as a CW hurt?

Comment: Surely this a nice **answer** since it's useful for the OP!